# How do I plot a 3D graph in 2D with color in octave?

Tags: plot, octave

I have a function z=f(x,y) and want to plot it using octave, but don't want the plot to be in 3d, as in

```
octave:1> x=(1:300);
octave:2> y=(1:300);
octave:3> [xx,yy]=meshgrid(x,y);
octave:4> A=sin(xx/100).*yy;
octave:5> mesh(x,y,A)
```

but rather in 2d using colors for the values of z, like what you get using the gnuplot instruction

```
gnuplot> plot 'a.txt' matrix w image
```

if I save the matrix A in the file a.txt. The closest I have found is the command contourf, but the as you can see if you try it,

```
octave:7> contourf(xx,yy,A)
```

the result is far from optimal... Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with either `contour(xx, yy, A)` if you're happy with contours or else perhaps `imshow(A)` and then mess around with the `colormap`?

Answer (score 2):

[`imagesc`](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Displaying-Images.html#XREFimagesc) will plot a matrix of your "z" values using colors:

```
> imagesc(x, y, A)
```

This will be inverted vertically compared to `contourf`, but that's easily fixed:

```
> imagesc(x, flipud(y), flipud(A))
```

And in your example you don't even need to provide the variables x and y:

```
> imagesc(A)
> imagesc(flipud(A))
```